# Quartz PDF-context based function fails (occasionally) with BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

Im Getting a Frequent enough BAD_ACCESS when i call this Quartz function:

```
CGContextDrawPDFPage ((CGContextRef)context, (CGPDFPageRef)pageRef);
```

Here is how i call it:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//translate, scale
CGPDFPageRef myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage ([PDFDocument sharedPDFDocument].documentData, pageNumber);
CGContextDrawPDFPage (context, myPageRef);//BAD_ACCESS HERE
return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();//autoreleased- saved on return
//close context
```

Neither variable is Nil, or have been released/auto released.

Here is the Stack trace, from the debugger:

[image]

Can anyone shed any light on this? Even some pointers on how i might investigate this better. it might not even be function specific.
 I probobly should mention this function is performed on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing the question, UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext and such functions where not thread safe, this was my issue. As of iOs 4.1+ many UI function are now thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for that returns your `myPageRef` and see if you have to retain it.